# TikZ: How does global/local [node distance] work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The expected output of this MWE is two overlaying nodes (i.e. `B` and `C`).

However, `\node [draw, right = 1cm of A] (B) {B};` successfully overrides the global setting of `node distance=2cm`, while `\node [draw, right = of A, node distance = 1cm] (C) {C};` doesn't.

So, why do both syntaxes result in different outputs?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
    \node [draw] (A) {A};
    \node [draw, right = 1cm of A] (B) {B};
    \node [draw, right = of A, node distance = 1cm] (C) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordering is important. The Ti*k*Z parser parses from left to right. This means that you need to *first* set the node distance (locally) to 1cm by saying `node distance = 1cm`, and then let Ti*k*Z compute the actual coordinates of the `C` node by saying `right = of A`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex',align=center]
    \node [draw] (A) {A};
    \node [draw, right = 1cm of A] (B) {B};
    \node [draw, node distance = 1cm, right = of A] (C) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, now the `B` and `C` nodes are on top of each other.

Comment: I didn't know my question is that naive

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I think it is better to delete this question

Comment: @Diaa I do not think your question is naive. Did I misread it? (Actually it took me a while to figure out how that works, and actually you can find some posts by high reputation users on this site who get it wrong IMHO, so I do not think this is a trivial question. But the decision of whether or not to delete is yours.)

Comment: I mean it is a stupid question XD that doesn't deserve to be asked :)

Comment: @Diaa The question became stupid only after seeing the answer. So please don't delete the question. Instead, downvote for making the question look stupid ;)

Answer (score 3):

The operation of the `node distance` key is particular and far from obvious. It only works **if and only if** there is an `of part` but **no** `shift part`.

I quote p 231 of 3.0.1a manual:

> `/tikz/node distance=<shifting part>` (no default, initially 1cm and
>   1cm) The value of this key is used as  is used **if and
>   only if** a `<of-part>` is present, but **no** `<shifting part>`.

Look at this example.

- Nodes colored blue do **not** have a `shifting part` in their code, so the `node distance` key is **active**.
- The red colored nodes have a `shifting part` and therefore the `node distance` key is **inactive**.

[image: examples]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {8,13,17}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[noeud/.style={draw,node distance=\i mm},
                    entre/.style={midway,draw=none,fill=white,inner sep =1pt}]
\draw[fill=green!10] (-1,-.1) rectangle (3,5);
\draw[help lines] (-1,-.1) grid (3,5);
% No shifting part
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={fill=blue!20,font=\scriptsize}]
\node[noeud,align=center] (a1) at (0,0) {node distance\\ actived};
\node[noeud] (b1) [above=of a1] {1};
\node[noeud] (c1) [above=of b1] {2};
\draw [<->](a1)--(b1)node[entre]{\i mm};
\draw [<->](b1)--(c1)node[entre]{\i mm};
\end{scope}
% Shifting part
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={fill=red!20,font=\scriptsize}]
\node[noeud,align=center] (a2) at (2,0) {node distance\\ inactived};
\node[noeud] (b2) [above=1cm of a2] {1};
\node[noeud] (c2) [above=1cm of b2] {2};
\draw [<->](a2)--(b2)node[entre]{1 cm};
\draw [<->](b2)--(c2)node[entre]{1 cm};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Your code is

```
right = 1cm of A
```

The `shifting part` is present and equal to `1 cm`. So the key `distance node=2cm` is **disabled**. Point B is therefore located **1 cm from A** as you have specified.

Then for point C, you write this:

```
 right = of A, node distance = 1cm
```

As there is **no** `shifting part` in this code, the `distance node=2cm` key is **active** and therefore the node is placed at `2cm`. Then you specify this distance again, but it has already been computed and so pgf does nothing more, as you can see with a 10 cm distance node key.

[image: code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm]
    \node [draw] (A) {A};
    \node [draw, right = 1cm of A] (B) {B};
    \node [draw, right =of A,circle,fill=red!40,opacity=.5,inner sep =10pt] (B) {B};
    \node [draw, right = of A, node distance = 10cm,fill=blue!40,opacity=.5,inner sep =10pt] (C) {C};
    \node [draw, node distance = 3cm, right = of A,fill=violet,opacity=.5,inner sep =10pt] (D) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator